# how to identify certain line break delete position

Tags: jquery, html

I have about 200 lines in text in a div. And it has 50 line breaks. If I want get the particular line break delete position in JQuery. How can I do that? Please help me out to do this. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: line break delete position? What do you mean?

Comment: If I delete particular line I want to get that position which line is deleted

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$("hr").filter(function() { return $(this).css("position") == "none" })
```

OR :

```
$("hr[style$='position: none;']")
```

To style all your `<hr>` tags.